# What's the difference between the various open source ATI video drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati

When trying to find information about open source ATI video drivers I have come across a number of different ones:

- radeon
- radeonhd
- r300g
- r600g

What are the differences in cards supported, 3D/2D performance, power management, and KMS support between these various drivers?

Answer (score 2):

X.org has information about [radeon](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature), and [gallium](http://www.x.org/wiki/GalliumStatus) (i.e. r300g and r600g). They have a similar page for [radeonhd](http://www.x.org/wiki/radeonhd%3afeature) but the driver is not actively developed any more.